# Within IF condition how does the <span> tag work

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to check `<span>` **id** with its text **Published** within IF condition and do some code. HTML code looks like this.

```
<span id="post-status-display">
                Published</span>
```

I tried this.but not work out

```
 function hide_edit_post(){ ?>
      <style type="text/css">
      var status=#post-status-display;
      if(status.text="Published"){
          .......
          //do some code
          .......
           }
      </style><?php
```

Comment: are you using `jQuery`?

Comment: you can't use `if-statement` with `css`

Comment: You seem to have a weird mix of CSS, JS and PHP there and I'm not sure what any of it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: I'm not using jQuery @zynkn

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't select a element from javascript with this:

```
var status=#post-status-display;
```

This should work:

```
var status= document.querySelector('#post-status-display').innerText;
if(status=="Published"){
     //do some code
}
```

Also, the `<style>` tags should not be there in the midle of your javascript...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `innerText` to get the raw text value in the element.

```js
const element = document.getElementById('post-status-display');
const text = element.innerText;
if (text === 'Published') {
  console.log('Yes it is:', text);
}
```

```html
<span id="post-status-display">
                Published</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

- You need to use innerHTML or innerText property to access your span contents, using innerHTML solution, following your code flow:-

```js
let status = document.getElementById('post-status-display').innerHTML;
        if (status === 'Published') {
            //do some code
        }
```

```html
<span id="post-status-display">Published</span>
```